# how to make smart pointer go out of scope at exit()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-2010

I've spent a bit of time writing an application for practice and i've taken a liking to using smart pointers throughout so as to avoid memory leaks in case i forgot to delete something. At the same time, i've also taken a liking to using exceptions to report failure in a constructor and attempt to handle it. When it cannot however, i would like for it to exit the program at that spot either through a call to assert() or exit(). However, using the crtdbg library in msvc, it reports a memory leak from the smart pointers that have anything dynamically allocated to them. This means one of two things to me. 1) the smart pointers never went out of scope of where they were allocated, and never deallocate, causing some memory leaks, or 2) crtdbg is not catching the deallocation because it doesn't exit at main. From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page though, using _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF ); at the begginning of the program will catch the leaks from any exit point, and I still get the memory leak errors using that.

So my question to you guys, will the memory actually be deallocated at exit or assert, and if not, might i be able to derive from std::shared_ptr and implement my own solution to cataloging dynamically allocated objects to be deallocated just before the call to exit or assert, or is that too much work for a more simple solution?

Comment: Why do you care about deallocation if the process dies anyway?

Comment: If you call `exit`, the stack is not unwound and local variables are not destroyed.  It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, though:  if you want local variables to be destroyed, throw an exception and `catch (...)` in `main()` to ensure the stack is unwound.

Comment: @ yuri kilochek: good question. does it matter? When i see the memory leak errors, it gets me to worrying, but if the process exits out, then do i still have to worry about it?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis you don't. OS frees all resources the process acquired during execution. However you might want to preserve some outer state anyway, like dumping some buffer to a file before termination.

Comment: @ yuri kilochek: well then i guess that's the answer to my question, ignore it and it goes away :P. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the program exits, the memory is reclaimed by the OS anyway, so if leaking is worrying you, it shouldn't.

If, however, you have logic in your destructors, and the objects must be destroyed - calling `exit` explicitly bypasses all deallocation. A workaround for this is to throw an exception where you would call exit, catch it in `main` and return.

```
#include "stdlib.h"

void foo()
{
   //exit(0);
   throw killException();
}

int main
{
   try
   {
      foo();
   }
   catch (killException& ex)
   {
      //exit program calling destructors
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
}
```

Comment: the first sentence is all i needed, the memory leak errors led me to believe that something was horribly wrong with the way i was doing this, but i guess just exiting the program releases all resources, so it doesn't matter :\. thanks a bunch. Will accept when i can

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: Something *is* wrong with the way you are doing this, regardless of whether memory is actually leaked or not :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: are multiple exit points really that bad? I'm exiting after handling an exception within the constuctor, because if this fails, then it is unsafe to use the object. If you try using the object after an exception is thrown then there will be errors. I would rather handle and exit right then within the constuctor, then propagate it up to be handled by an outside user, because then they could continue the program and just go about using it. What else would you suggest in this situation?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: The constructor should fail with an exception, but that does not mean that the whole application should die. Some higher level code might be able to handle the issue. The higher level logic should have the opportunity to recover from the error condition.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is not with memory, but other resources. The OS will (in most cases, unless you are running an embedded system) recover the memory from the process when it terminates, so memory will not be *leaked* in the OS. The actual problem might be with other resources, external to your process that might need to be released before your process completes...

At any rate, why do you prefer to `abort` or `exit` rather than letting the exception propagate up? In general you should handle only the exceptions that you want to manage and let the others fall through. While you might not be able to recover from it, your caller might actually be able to. By capturing the exception and exiting the program on the spot you are removing the choice of handling from the users.